# ng-repeat empty on load when applying ng-model filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this code :

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search..." ng-model="query" />
<table ng-controller="Employees" ng-init="init()">
  <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees | filter:{ name: query }">
    <td>{{employee.name}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The problem is that when the page loads, there is nothing in the table, until I type something in the search input. Then everything matching appears, and if I clear the input, all the employees will be displayed (as it should be on load).

I don't have this problem if I write `filter: query` instead of `filter:{ name: query }`.

How can I have all the data displayed on load with `filter:{ name: query }`?

Comment: Can you provide a jsFiddle or Plunker that shows the problem?  I tried to replicate the issue, and it worked for me.

Comment: It would take some time to port my app to jsFiddle because it's pretty complex, I made this example to illustrate but I guess the problem came from somewhere else... Anyway, Shay Friedman's answer worked for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line to the `Employees` controller:

```
$scope.query = '';
```